# Why doesn't initializer_list automatically convert to array?

Tags: c++, c++11

This doesn't work:

```
auto A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

The reason being that `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is deduced to be an `initializer_list` which cannot be used to initialize an array. My arguments against this:

1. If the language can deduce the size of type of an `initializer_list`, it has no problem doing the same for an array. Template argument deduction will solve issues of inconsistent types
2. `initializer_list`s aren't meant to be containers, whereas an array "can".

It would be nice if if the elements were automatically copied into an array and the `initializer_list` "disappears", just like initializing an array with a string literal. How come there's no special rule for this?

Comment: [Interestingly enough](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1984.pdf) Page 6: "Note that depending on the work on initializers we may wish to revisit this part. For example, we may wish to enable auto x[] = {a, b, c};". My guess is with the advent of `std::array` and the hopefully soon-to-be adopted [`make_array`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4391.html) this syntax would be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Complaining on Stack Overflow is not likely to change design decisions you know.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well I argue against that. 1) I'm not complaining. People have asked about design decisions, proposals and reasons why a feature wouldn't be feasible before, and it's fostered lots of positive discussion. 2) People who sit in the standards commitee seat, write proposals, or otherwise know a lot about the language use StackOverflow. This is as good of a place to "complain" than any. It shouldn't have to be tucked away in a mailing list where the greater public can't also benefit from it.

Comment: But SO is for Q and A. The answer to this question in the context of SO is "the standard says so"  I'm not saying that I don't agree with you (I do),  it just doesn't belong here. Find a forum.